# Updating Yocto causes exception 'bb.data' has no attribute 'getVar'

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to upgrade a project which is using Yocto 1.6 Fido, up to Yocto 2.6 Thud.

I receive the following exception during a build. An issue with the meta-eca layer

```
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/poky-thud/build- 
bbgw/../meta-eca/meta-iot/recipes-web/the-thing-system/steward_git.bb                                                                                         
| ETA:  0:01:02

Traceback (most recent call last):

bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable TTS_ARCH[:=], 
expression was ${@get_arch(bb, d)} which triggered exception AttributeError:

module 'bb.data' has no attribute 'getVar'
```

I guess 'getVar' is deprecated somehow.

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not `getVar` what is deprecated, but the way to use/access it. You only need BitBake´s data dictionary structure (`d`) in order to access to its environment variables. You should modify the recipe as follows:

```
def get_arch(d):
    val = (d.getVar("MACHINEOVERRIDES", True) or "")
    if val.find("genericx86") > 0:
        return "--arch=i686"
    elif val.find("x86") > 0:
        return "--arch=i686"
    elif val.find("arm") > 0:
        return "--arch=arm"
    else:
        return ""

# Always compile 32-bit in npm because many modules that npm
# compiles do not support 64 bit in x86.
TTS_ARCH := "${@get_arch(d)}"
```

For futher information refer to the [BitBake user manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#functions-for-accessing-datastore-variables)